# Add log text payload to GCP log based alert

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

How can I include log text payload in the Documentation section of a log-based alert that I created in GCP Log Explorer?

I tried to add the text payload to policy conditions section and also tried to Using variables in documentation templates from here:
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/doc-variables#null-values

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.